# Can I upload a pdf file along with a question/answer?

Tags: support

I had written down an answer for my own question and would like get review comments/suggestion. Also it might be helpful for others to answer  the question in a better way. Problem is I had written it down in latex and made it into a pdf document. I want to know if there is any way I can upload a pdf or any workaround to this problem.

Comment: Why not just post the LaTeX itself?

Comment: @Akhil Mathew : Do you mean copying the contents of the latex file into the answer box ? It is not working, because it is not accepting several syntax elements like \begin{equation}, and things like that.

Comment: Dear Rajesh, \begin{equation} should be converted to a double dollar sign. If you're having serious difficulties, I'd encourage you just to post the TeX itself and let someone else fix it (if you post a PDF, it can't be edited).

Comment: @Akhil : there are some arrays of equations and numbering of equations which are creating the problems, i cannot convert them to equations between double dollars, as loose numbering and also equation arrays. Please let me know whether such things are possible.

Comment: Have a look at this related question: [Creating simple graphs](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1819/2575). My answer there might be of interest for you `:-)`

Comment: You still could use WriteLaTeX or something similar to share both LaTeX source and pdf-file.

Comment: An answer to [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17081/using-lyx-to-write-answers-for-posts) contains some suggestions on converting the LaTeX source to MarkDown+MathJax. (Assuming you use only very limited subset of LaTeX commands.)

Comment: As of 2014: Equation numbering has been implemented, and surrounding display equation environments with double dollar signs is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical answer is **no**. The Math.SE site does not support uploads/embeddings of `pdf` files. If you insist on sharing a `pdf` file, you should consider using some-sort of "Digital Locker" service (if you don't have your own website) and paste a link.

However, I strongly suggest against that. When material can easily be presented in textual format included on the site, it should be done so. This is so that your answer will be useful for the next person who comes along (in the event of link rot and so on). It is better to re-type it in a mix of mark-down and MathJax formatted mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

If you surround the whole `eqnarray` block with double dollar signs, it works. That is,

```
$$\begin{eqnarray}
e^{i\pi} + 1 & = & 0 \\
E & = & mc^2
\end{eqnarray}$$
```

becomes

$$\begin{eqnarray}
e^{i\pi} + 1 & = & 0 \\
E & = & mc^2
\end{eqnarray}$$

It seems that [MathJax doesn't support equation numbering yet](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/71). You can always try to give the equation a number or name "by hand" in the surrounding text.

P.S. I would suggest, as a matter of general practice, using the `align` environment instead of `eqnarray`. See the article "[Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)" by Lars Madsen.